# How to resize elements such as pictures, containers, and text so that it can fit devices of any size?

Tags: html, css

I should mention that my screen resolution is 1920x1080, but we are also using computers that have a shorter width, if I increase my browser to 150%, the pictures, and the header increase in size and move out of place in relation to the UL which stays in place. I will post my code below if anyone knows what I did wrong in my css code:

```
<body>
<z13>
<img src="marioswine.png" style = "display: block; margin: 0 auto;" 
alt="cactxt" height = "125px" class = "center"/>
</z13>

<e2><img src="y.png" style = "display: block; margin: 0 auto;" alt="albany" 
class = "strip"/></e2>

<h2 class = "announcement"> Announcements</h2>




<ul class = "wall">
<li class = "bars"></li>
</ul>


<div style = "position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 180px;">
<button id = "home" class = "strip"> HOME </button>
<button id = "about"> About Us </button>
<button id = "locations"> Locations </button>
<button id = "wine"> wine </button>
<button id = "beer"> beer </button>
<button id = "spirits"> spirits </button>
<button id = "lottery"> lottery </button>
<button id = "contact"> Contact Us </button>


</div>

<div>

<d>


<p>We are the greatest wine in all of wine....its gonne be yuuuuuuuge!!!!! 
</p>
</d>

</div>


<div class="slideshow-container" style = "position: absolute; left: 260px; 
top: 180px;">

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
<img src="wine.jpg" style="width:100%">
<div class="text">Awesome wine</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
<img src="beer.jpg" style="width:100%">
<div class="text">Great Beer!</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
<img src="spirits.png" style="width:100%">
<div class="text">The spirit of spirits!!</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
```

```
//This is my CSS code, I think the real problem should be here

<style type = "text/css">


//This is what i tried to use to be able to fit my content into a device of 
any size, but it's not working  

    body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }

    z11{
    top: -50px;
    position: absolute;
    }

    z12{
    top: 5px;
    position: absolute;

    }

            z13{
    top: 0px;
    left: 40%;
    //right: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    }

    .center {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%;
    }
        .strip {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
    }


    a3{ position: absolute;
        top: 175px;
        left: 245px;
    }

    b{  position: absolute;
        top: 350px;
        left: 255px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    c{
    position: absolute;
    top: 225px;
    right: 300px;
    }

        d{
    position: absolute;
    top: 525px;
    left: 260px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 50%;
    min-width: 20%;
    //height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;

    }

    e{
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    right: 5px;
    //max-width: 50%;
    width: 500px;
    }


    e2{
        position: absolute;
        top: 175px;
        left: 775px;
        //max-width: 100%;

    }

    ul.wall{position: fixed;
        position: absolute;
        list-style-type:none;
        top: 125px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #2b2622;
    }

    li.bars{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    .side {
background-color: #555555; /* black */
color: white;
width: 250px;
border: none;
padding: 39px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
font-size: 18px;
}

    button {
background-color: #555555; /* black */
color: white;
width: 250px;
border: none;
padding: 39px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
font-size: 18px;

-webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
transition-duration: 0.4s;
}


    button:hover {
background-color: #688396; /* Green */
color: black;
box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}


    h2.announcement{
 position: absolute;
    top: 175px;
    left: 1400px;

}




</style>



<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
max-width: 500px;
position: relative;
margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 90%;
width: auto;
padding: 16px;
margin-top: -22px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;
transition: 0.6s ease;
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
left: 90.7%;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
//width: 45px;
}

.prev {
left: 0%;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
width: 45px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.next:hover {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
color: #f2f2f2;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 8px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
color: #f2f2f2;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
cursor: pointer;
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
margin: 0 2px;
//background-color: #bbb;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
 background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
-webkit-animation-name: fade;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
animation-name: fade;
animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .4} 
to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .4} 
to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
.prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use responsive web design. Please check [HTML Responsive Web Design](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)